# Are CMOS outputs high-Z when unpowered?

Tags: mosfet, gpio

If a microcontroller I/O pin drives an external MOSFET, and the microcontroller's power is turned off, will that MOSFET's gate be floating? I know sometimes a resistor is added to ground, but are there risks if I don't place the resistor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When turned off, the output state is undefined (almost certainly pretty high impedance, but there may be protection diodes and other features that will cause variations between parts), so it's best not to assume anything about it unless the datasheet specifies something definite. Of course you can test the output impedance yourself with a multimeter if you want to get an actual figure to go from.

If your design requires an output line to not be left floating when the micro is off, then definitely use the resistor. This is good practice anyway for cases where the microcontroller may malfunction (or the pin becomes physically disconnected), so the pin has a "default" state.

Comment: Correct, but I'd like to point that some microcontrollers can leak to the rails, so the discrete resistor may create a static path that will leak. The datasheet should specify the behavior of the I/O ports when the uC is in low power mode or turned off.

Answer (score 6):

Both a CMOS output and a MOSFET gate can be high-impedance, so the voltage at their connection can be determined by 'random' things like stray capacitive or inductive coupling, leaking through high resistances (dirt on your PCB) or statics (fingers touching your traces).

If you care whether the MOSFET is on or off in such a situation the gate-to-ground resistor (for an N-FET) is definitely mandatory.

Another good reason for this resistor is that it bleeds any static charge that otherwise might accumulate and destroy the gate. This is less likely with modern micro-controllers that have a protection circuit at their I/O pins, but that circuit is designed to protect the IC itself, not an external FET.

So by all means: yes, include the resistor!

Answer (score 5):

Many, though not all, CMOS devices to have either deliberate or parasitic diodes between their pins and the rails.  Though the design of CMOS inputs does not inherently create parasitic diodes, the design of a normal CMOS output does.  In particular, the normal way of wiring a transistor to drive an output low creates a diode from V<sub>SS</sub> to that output, and the normal way of wiring a transistor to drive an output high creates a diode from that output to V<sub>DD</sub>.  In the days before mixed-voltage logic, outputs which could drive both high and low would almost always have parasitic diodes to the rails, and inputs would often have deliberately-placed diodes to protect them against damage from electro-static discharge.  Many newer programmable logic devices and microcontrollers, however, have circuitry which eliminates the high-side diodes on at least some of the I/O ports.

If you want to ensure that a MOSFET is turned off when a processor is not deliberately driving it high, you should probably use a pull-down resistor.  This will waste a little current when the MOSFET is turned on, but it need not waste much.  In most cases, 1-50uA wasted on such a resistor will be minor compared to the amount of current drawn by the thing being switched.

Answer (score -1):

It's not really a question of how the microcontroller pins behave when powered off, but how the MOSFET behaves.  Being insulated-gate devices, MOSFETs don't need any current to turn them on or off.  Consequently, leakage through the PCB dielectric or package materials will rule out any such thing as a "floating" MOSFET gate, even if the microcontroller output itself can be said to "float" when the chip is powered down.

It would be extremely poor practice to count on any particular behavior from the MOSFET in the situation you're talking about.  Use the resistor.  Again, the gate isn't going to draw any current, so even 1M would be fine.

Comment: You seem to contradict yourself. First you say the "leakage through the PCB dielectric" (sic) will rule out a floating gate, but then you say the resistor is still required. Which one is it? (I can't measure the PCB resistance because too high, I'm not sure if that leakage is correct).

Comment: Leakage through the dielectric could go to either Gnd, Vcc, or somewhere else.  You don't want to leave it to chance.